# file_get_contents(https://url) fails

Tags: php, ssl, file-get-contents

On my Ubuntu 12.04 server running PHP 5.5 on Lighttpd I have

- allow_url_fopen On
- allow_url_include On
- OpenSSL Support Enabled
- OpenSSL Library/Header Version 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012

I am not sure this is right but I also put in extension=openssl.so in my php.ini file and rebooted by server.  I see no untoward error messages in my logs.

Nevertheless I still get *failed to open stream: Connection timed out*.  The same URL without https works just fine.  Am I missing something

Comment: if it was a php config issue, you'd just get no-such-function or no handler available. connection timed out points more towards a network issue, e.g. firewall blocking outgoing requests on port 443.

Comment: @Marc B if you mention network issue in an answer I will accept it :-)

Comment: Based on your answer below, I'm voting to close as a problem that cannot be reproduced (presuming you fixed your Asian server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone said above this is a network issue.  Actually, I was wrong when I said that *http://exmaple.com* worked whilst *https://example.com* did not.  I run four servers, call them **A, B, C & D** at different global locations - two in the US, one in Europe and one in Asia.  The URL that I am trying to reach is for another server in the US.  After posting this question and reviewing the various comments I explored matters a bit more and discovered that my file_get_contents call was failing **only** from the Asian server.  TraceRoute revealed that the Asian server is simply unable to locate the one I want to reach.  So as someone here said - this is a network issue.  I am posting this answer so anyone who runs into this thread in quest of a solution to a similar problem realizes that this might well be the problem rather than a PHP configuration thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities, but you will be able to find out more about what the reason is if you just try to `curl` the HTTPs URL from the command line of the server where the code is running.

```
curl -v https://url
```

Common problems would be that the https cert at `url` is not valid, or that outgoing https connections are blocked on your server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried that.  curl reports: "about to..." followed by trying *IP Address* hangs around for a bit and then reports "Couldn't connect to that host", curl: (7).  There is no issue with the url not having SSL and Port 443 open - I know it does.

Comment: I should mention that I am running Ubuntu's UFW which has been configured to allow only a handful of incoming ports.  However, the defaults I see in *ufw status verbose* explictly states Default:deny(incoming) allow(outgoing) so going out on 443 is not the issue.